# jQuery only return html code of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite confused... do you know, why jquery return me only HTML code of element?

It returns only smth like this:

```
[<input type="text" name="preview_image" />]
```

My example:

```
$('input[type=file][name=preview_image].file-upload').fileupload({
        url: window.fileUpload.uploadUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For the line: `console.log($(this));`, the `this` in this context refers to the actual `input` element. If you replace the console log with `console.log(data);` you would get information pertaining to the file upload (after it has completed).

Comment: Yeah, understand. And is there any way, how to access used input a use jquery methods, like `closest`....